# Firebase - IN query not working in where clause getting blank array as result

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to filter my data with IN query it's not showing me the result I am getting a blank array in result I have tried the same thing in the firebase console. I am not getting result there as well.

My data is
messages/01fjubNOf8oYODitr1h6 In this path, I have keys - name, message, participants

```
{
  name: "Pawan arora",
  message: "test",
  participants: ["33", "127"]
},
{
  name: "TEST NAME",
  message: "not working",
  participants: ["114", "127"]
}
{
  name: "TEST DATA",
  message: "new",
  participants: ["114", "33"]
}
```

I tried in the query to filter data my query is

`.collection("messages").where("participants", "in", ["33", "127"])`

Here I should get the first object as a result

[Firebase database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0t94.png)

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate answers which are valid for `in` as well. Your array is populated with objects.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Maybe there is some misunderstanding to see my data on firebase

I have data be like

groups/01fjubNOf8oYODitr1h6

In this path, I have keys  - name, message, participants 

Here in groups collection, I want to filter it by  participants key

Comment: @RenaudTarneci have edit my question please have a look at this again. also i am not able to reopen it can you please repoen it as well

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your Firestore database. Question is reopened.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have added a link for the image in my question. please have a look

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0t94.png

Comment: I see that you adapted the name of the collection to `messages`. Isn't it working now? Do you see any error? Is there any security rule?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec NO I have not added any security rule for this collection. Also, I am not seeing any error

Comment: How do you log error?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec  i am logging any error for now. but I am trying this to filter in cloud firestore console it's not working there as well.For ref check screenshot

https://prnt.sc/wiuv03

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `array-contains-any` operator instead when filtering arrays.

Try this:

```
.collection("messages").where("participants", "array-contains-any", ["33", "127"])
```

For details check [this blogpost](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html).

Comment: Actually, my requirement is to get where a particular id get matched not like where it contains 

For example, I have 3 messages with participants id [33, 127] and [114, 127] and [33, 114]

If I applied filter with id 33, 127 then i should only [33, 127]

Can anyone please help me here which filter i should use now

Comment: Oh, i see, in this case have you tried double brackets?  Like `.collection("messages").where("participants", "in", [["33", "127"]])`.

Comment: Thanks :) Wooah!!

It's working for me but I have to reorder my array while creating and getting the collection 

Can you please tell me one thing is it documented anywhere? Because I am not finding this method anywhere in docs

Comment: I mean it just looks not for string objects but for arrays. In documentation strings are just for example, I believe you can filter by any object type.

Comment: Hey, @Emil Gi with your above solution with two brackets I got a problem here in one more scenario. For example, I have 4 messages with participants id [33, 127] and [114, 127] and [33, 114, 127] and [33, 114] If I applied filter with id 33, 127 then I should get two results here [33, 127], [33, 114, 127] but I am receiving only one here [33, 127]

Can you please help me to achieve this one?